# flipping a multi-dimensional array java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have a class that creates a canvas of characters with a desired width and height.

within this i have a method drawLetter() (which basically changes the characters so that a letter appears on the canvas (like very simple ASCII art)

i have 3 other methods rotateClockwise, flipHorizontal, and flipVertical

rotate and flipHorizontal i have done fine and they work but i cannot seem to work out where im going wrong with flipping the array vertically (out of interest i think i have horizontal and vertical the wrong way round but ill put a sample of what im trying to get done below)

this is what i cant work out:

this:

```
# # # ~
~ # ~ ~
~ # ~ ~
~ ~ ~ ~
```

to this:

```
~ # # #
~ ~ # ~
~ ~ # ~
~ ~ ~ ~
```

obviously it will be done in a for loop like my other methods, below i will post the method i have done already for horizontal and rotate clockwise to prove its not homework i cant do

```
void mirrorHorizontally()
{
    char[][]horizontalImage = new char[height][width];

    for (int i = 0; i < height /2; i++)
    { 
       for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
       {  
           horizontalImage[height - (i+1)][j] = canvasArray[i][j];           
           horizontalImage[i][j] = canvasArray[height - (i+1)][j];
       }
    }   
    printPicture(horizontalImage);
}


void rotateClockwise()
{
    char[][] rotatedImage = new char[height][width];

    for(int i=0; i< canvasArray.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j= canvasArray.length-1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            rotatedImage[i][rotatedImage.length-1-j] = canvasArray[j][i]; 
        }
    }

    printPicture(rotatedImage);
}
```

canvasArray is the original image out of interest in a char[][] class variable

Comment: What is your problem?  Is the swapping not working properly?

Comment: to be honest i just cant work out how to structure the for loop for this swap of values

Comment: iv done it before using a 2D char[] using string arrays etc to make it work but im trying to make this simple app better by using a multi-dimensional array instead

Comment: Essentially, it's the same as `mirrorHorizontally()`, just with access patterns for height/width reverse.  However, you might want to look into using a standard library for this: Apache's [ArrayUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html) has a `reverse(...)` method, which could be used on the various levels of arrays.

Comment: thanks but im not using libraries its not the functionality i want its more that this seemed like a good example to look at to learn how multi dimensional arrays work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should suit your needs:

```
public static char[][] mirror(int width, int height, char[][] in) {
    char[][] out = new char[height][width];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            out[i][width - j - 1] = in[i][j];
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

For example:

```
char[][] in = new char[][] {
    new char[] { '#', '#', '#', '~' },
    new char[] { '~', '#', '~', '~' },
    new char[] { '~', '#', '~', '~' },
    new char[] { '~', '~', '~', '~' },
    new char[] { '~', '~', '~', '~' }
};

for (char[] line : mirror(4, 5, in)) {
    for (char row : line) {
        System.out.print(row);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Prints:

```
~###
~~#~
~~#~
~~~~
~~~~
```

Comment: +1, Not going to post my complicated method after reading this ;)

Comment: thank you very much that was exactly what i was looking for. exactly the same style as i have been doing in previous methods, it was simply one of those times when iv been looking at it too long and not seen the obvious, thanks again