# How to mirror an image horizontally using Java 2D Arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, image, for-loop, 2d

Greetings guys and girls I've stumbled into a problem I can't seem to figure out, and the similar posts have a different structure than what I'm using. Therefore I'd really appreciate some guidance. Let's take a look at my horizontal mirror method:

```
  public void  mirrorHorizontal(){
  Pixel[][] pixels = this.getPixels2D();     
  Pixel topPixel = null;     
  Pixel bottomPixel = null;     
  int width = pixels[0].length;     
  for (int row = 0; row < pixels.length / 2; row++){       
      for (int col = 0; col < width; col++){         
          bottomPixel = pixels[row][col];        
          topPixel = pixels[row][col];         
          bottomPixel.setColor(topPixel.getColor());       
      }     
  } }
```

Lets establish that this code was provided to use and modify so I will do my best to explain.

In this for loop what I did was cut the rows in half by diving the pixels.length by 2 so I can achieve the top picture at the top, and one on the bottom.

```
for (int row = 0; row < pixels.length / 2; row++){
```

So I believe here is my problem:

```
bottomPixel = pixels[row][col];        
topPixel = pixels[row][col];
```

I do not know what to put inside the bottomPixel [row][col]

I believe it has to render something like this:

1. 1 2 3 4
2. 5 6 7 8
3. 5 6 7 8
4. 1 2 3 4

However I'm not sure how to modify it to achieve that.

*This uses two modified for loops & different values to achieve similar effects to flipping a multi-dimensional array java by AngryDuck.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [flipping a multi-dimensional array java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007264/flipping-a-multi-dimensional-array-java)

Comment: I reviewed the link and that is similar topic but the difference is in the loops and values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in your exsample the `bottomPixel` and `topPixel` are exactly the same.

If I understood your question correctly, this will solve your problem:

```
for (int row = 0; row < pixels.length / 2; row++){       
  for (int col = 0; col < pixels[0].length; col++){                 
      topPixel = pixels[row][col];  
      bottomPixel = pixels[(pixels.length - 1) - i][col];       
      bottomPixel.setColor(topPixel.getColor());       
  }     
}
```

I changed the row coordinate of `bottomPixel` so it will take the mirrored coordinate from the bottom. But this only works if your image has exactly `pixels.length / 2` rows.

Comment: That fixed the problem only change I had to make was replace the i with row. Thank you I really appreciate it.