# How to return a Matrix variable with a flip method?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, dimension

i wrote the following code :

```
public class Matrix
{
    private final int[][] array;
    private final int size1;
    private final int size2;
Matrix(int size1,int size2)
    {
        this.size1=size1;
        this.size2=size2;
        this.array=new int[size1][size2];
    }

    Matrix(int[][] color)
    {
        this.size1=color.length;
        this.size2=color[0].length;
        this.array= new int[size1][size2];

        for(int row=0;row<size1;row++)
        {
            for(int column=0;column<size2;column++)
            {
                this.array[row][column]=color[row][column];
            }
        }
    }

    }
    public Matrix flipVertically()
    {
     Matrix newArray=new Matrix(array);
    for(int row=size1-1;row>=0;row--)
    {
        for(int column=0;column<array[row].length;column++)
        {
           newArray[row][column]=array[size1][size2];     
    }
}
return newArray;
}
}
```

and my method needs to return a new Matrix which inside of it, the first row becomes the last row, the second row becomes the second last row and so on...

i wrote this code but i have 2 problems:

1. when i write `newArray[row][column]=array[size1][size2]`;
   it writes me : Matrix required but array found. why does it writes it? and how can i fix it?
2. what does it means to return "Metrix" variable? how does it looks like?

Thank you !

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/15007264/5184092. See if that helps you out.

Comment: Also your `newArray[row][column]=array[size1][size2]`, if you get your for loop working correctly, will put the last item in `array` into every slot of `newArray`. Thus not flipping your matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are treating an instance of `Matrix` like it is an array; it is not. It *has* an array. If you want to manipulate the internal array of the `newArray` instance (I highly recommend renaming that variable to `newMatrix`), then you can do so by accessing `newArray.array`.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right here is what you want:

```
public class Matrix {

  private final int[][] array;
  private final int size1;
  private final int size2;

  Matrix(int size1, int size2) {
    this.size1 = size1;
    this.size2 = size2;
    this.array = new int[size1][size2];
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for (int[] arr: array)
      builder.append(Arrays.toString(arr) + "\n");

    return "Matrix{" +
        "array=\n" + builder +
        '}';
  }

  Matrix(int[][] color) {
    this.size1 = color.length;
    this.size2 = color[0].length;
    this.array = new int[size1][size2];

    for (int row = 0; row < size1; row++) {
      for (int column = 0; column < size2; column++) {
        this.array[row][column] = color[row][column];
      }
    }


  }

  public Matrix flipVertically() {
    int start = 0, end = size1 - 1;

    while (start < end) {
      int[] tmp = array[start];
      array[start] = array[end];
      array[end] = tmp;
      start++;
      end--;
    }

    return this;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix(new int[][]{{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}});
    System.out.println(matrix.flipVertically());
    matrix = new Matrix(new int[][]{{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}, {10,11,12}});
    System.out.println(matrix.flipVertically());
    matrix = new Matrix(new int[][]{{1}});
    System.out.println(matrix.flipVertically());
    matrix = new Matrix(new int[][]{{1},{2},{3}});
    System.out.println(matrix.flipVertically());
  }
```

Output:

```
Matrix{array=
[7, 8, 9]
[4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3]
}
Matrix{array=
[10, 11, 12]
[7, 8, 9]
[4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3]
}
Matrix{array=
[1]
}
Matrix{array=
[3]
[2]
[1]
}
```

To answer your questions:

1. As mentioned above you are creating a new instance of Matrix class, not 
   an array. Also, this `newArray[row][column]=array[size1][size2];` is 
   not how you can copy an array in java, though I don't think you
   need to copy it at all - see my implementation. Anyway if want to copy 
   your array, please refer to this 
   [copy a 2d array in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686425/copy-a-2d-array-in-java)
2. Variable of type matrix you can create this
   way:  `Matrix matrix = new Matrix(new int[][]{{1,2,3}, {4,5,6},
   {7,8,9}});`. In my code I just return `this` witch is a reference to
   itself.

P.S. Suggestions for improvement of your code: add getters and setters, make your constructor public if there is no reason keep it `friendly`, check for corner cases when you have empty array passed to constructor....