# Reverse diagonal traversal of a matrix (start from top right side)

Tags: java, matrix, diagonal

I have a code from another site, which gives me the Zigzag (or diagonal) traversal of Matrix.

Given array in the code:

```
1     2     3     4
5     6     7     8
9    10    11    12
13    14    15    16
17    18    19    20
```

For the given array in the code, the output is:

```
1
5 2
9 6 3
13 10 7 4
17 14 11 8
18 15 12
19 16
20
```

So it starts from the top left side. (From 1)

I want to make it start from the top right side, so the first element is "4", the second element is "8 3", third is "12 7 2", fourth is "16 11 6 1" etc... But I can't make it.
Could you help me rewriting the code for me?

```
class GFG {
    static final int ROW = 5;
    static final int COL = 4;
 
    static int min(int a, int b)
    {
        return (a < b) ? a : b;
    }
 
    static int min(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        return min(min(a, b), c);
    }
 
    static int max(int a, int b)
    {
         return (a > b) ? a : b;
    }
 
    static void diagonalOrder(int matrix[][])
    {

        for (int line = 1; line <= (ROW + COL - 1); line++) {
 
            int start_col = max(0, line - ROW);
 
            int count = min(line, (COL - start_col), ROW);
 
            for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
                System.out.print(matrix[min(ROW, line)- j- 1][start_col + j]+ " ");
 
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
 
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int M[][] = {
            { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
            { 5, 6, 7, 8 },
            { 9, 10, 11, 12 },
            { 13, 14, 15, 16 },
            { 17, 18, 19, 20 },
        };
 
        System.out.print(
            "\nDiagonal printing of matrix is \n");
        diagonalOrder(M);
    }
}
```

I tried to make it but it didn't work properly.

Comment: If you already have working code that can print the matrix diagonals starting from top left corner why don't you simply flip (mirror) the matrix and enter the flipped matrix into your working code? With flipping the matrix I mean that the 4th column becomes the 1st, 3rd column the 2nd and so on. Take a look here: [flipping a multi-demensional array java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007264/flipping-a-multi-dimensional-array-java).

Comment: Why explain what you want and not also show it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Flipping the matrix horizontally worked for me, thanks for the answers.

[flipping a multi-dimensional array java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007264/flipping-a-multi-dimensional-array-java)